# Edit vis.gam plots to show dates

Tags: r, plot, gam, mgcv

I have created a Generalized Additive Model using the mgcv package and would like to plot a 3D graph using the vis.gam function. One of the controls is a date. Here is some reproducible code:

```
Date <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("2008-12-30"), as.Date("2012-01-04"), by="weeks"))
Control <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:100, 79*2, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
Response <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:100, 79*2, replace=TRUE), ncol=1))
df <- data.frame(Date,Control,Response)
colnames(df)[2:3] <- c("Control","Response")
library(mgcv)
GAM <- gam(Response ~   s(Control)+s(as.numeric(Date)),
        family=gaussian,  data= df)
vis.gam(GAM,n.grid = 100, theta = 50, phi = 32, zlab = "Response",ylab = "Date",xlab="Control",
    ticktype = "detailed", color = "topo")
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to edit the y-axis so this shows the original dates, rather than the converted numerical values? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You could probably make use of [this post](http://entrenchant.blogspot.com/2014/03/custom-tick-labels-in-r-perspective.html) to achieve what you want.